# Outlook 2013 VBA display Shared Calendar

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar, outlook-2013

I've got some VBa code that opens the Calendar in a new window, but I now need it to display the shared calendars that I've already got setup, but the only code I can find Creates a new shared calendar in the new window i've just created;

```
Sub DispCalendars()
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNms As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim myExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim SharedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set myNms = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNms.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    Set myExplorer = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
    Set myExplorer.CurrentFolder = myFolder
    Set myRecipient = myNms.CreateRecipient("Bob the Builder")
    Set SharedFolder = myNms.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    myExplorer.SelectFolder SharedFolder
End Sub
```

If I change to 'myRecipient' part to just a name, it errors and I can't seem to work it out.

[Here](http://s22.postimg.org/t6d3yu30h/Untitled.png) is something how it looks (when I do it manually) and I would like to recreate it in code.

Comment: So the problem is that GetSharedDefaultFolder returns an error for a particular name? What is the exact error? Can Outlook resolve it if you type the same value in the To edit box and hit Ctrl+K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the line to show the Folder selected in Outlook

```
    myExplorer.CurrentFolder = SharedFolder
```

i guess instead of the "selectfolder"-line... also some of the other lines could be deleted, espacially

Set myExplorer.CurrentFolder = myFolder

as it does not make sende to open two Folders one after another in one Sub.

Yours
Max